# How does this JavaScript open Windows Settings in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, security, firefox, windows-10

After a new install of Firefox 45 Developer Edition, I saw this page. It has a button ("Let's do it") that when clicked, somehow opens up the **Choose default apps** settings page in Windows 10.

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/windows-10/welcome/?utm_source=firefox-browser&utm_medium=firefox-browser

How is this done? I couldn't find anything through the Developer Console in the labyrinthine code on that page. Besides, I would have thought browsers don't allow JavaScript to open something as sensitive as the Settings app.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page fires a custom event of type `mozUITour` on the document. This event is handled in the browser by [`content-UITour.js`](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/browser/components/uitour/content-UITour.js), which shovels out most of the actual processing to [`UITour.jsm`](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/browser/components/uitour/UITour.jsm). The unobfuscated client-side code can be viewed in [`UITour-lib.js`](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/browser/components/uitour/UITour-lib.js).

Cutting through all the client-side abstraction, this is what’s happening:

```
document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('mozUITour', {
    bubbles: true,
    detail: {
        action: 'setConfiguration',
        data: {
            configuration: 'defaultBrowser'
        }
    }
}));
```

Then in the browser, it handles the event, dispatches the event in another internal event queue, where it will be processed by calling into `nsIShellService::setDefaultBrowser`, implemented by [`nsWindowsShellService.cpp`](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/22f51211915b/browser/components/shell/nsWindowsShellService.cpp#l926). On what’s currently line 943, we have:

```
if (IsWin10OrLater()) {
  rv = LaunchModernSettingsDialogDefaultApps();
} else {
  rv = LaunchControlPanelDefaultsSelectionUI();
}
```

And `LaunchModernSettingsDialogDefaultApps`, I think, is a pretty descriptive function name.

Now, from your comment, “in a way that one could use it on their own page, for example”? Not so likely. `content-UITour.js` checks that the page has the `uitour` permission. From [`browser/app/permissions`](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/browser/app/permissions), we have:

```
# UITour
origin  uitour  1   https://www.mozilla.org
origin  uitour  1   https://self-repair.mozilla.org
origin  uitour  1   https://support.mozilla.org
origin  uitour  1   about:home
```

So unless you’re `www.mozilla.org`, `self-repair.mozilla.org`, `support.mozilla.org`, or `about:home`, you can’t do it, at least not by default. Before Firefox 15 (17 with a manual settings change, see [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=546848) for more information), you might be able to use [`netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege`](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/jssec.html#privs) to request extra permissions from the browser, but that’s not around any more, and I’m not sure that even touches the same permission mechanism.

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot of useful info. But it doesn't answer how (as in what code) was used to trigger the settings app. In a way that one could use it on their own page for example.

Comment: Nice, very detailed answer! (thanks for the edit). Guess it was too good to be true after all.