# Launch Windows 10 Settings using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, windows-10

Using [chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/?brand=CHBD&gclid=CjwKCAjwxOvsBRAjEiwAuY7L8oFEV2eTSDkeUtSi--P067OFxAAXzNgdv2CIqVgYTwD4rFw3-49aExoCozkQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds), I tried going to [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ph/p/netflix/9wzdncrfj3tj?cid=msft_web_appsforwindows_spotlight#activetab=pivot:overviewtab) and when I click the button `GET` to install an app, a dialog shows up and asks to open Microsoft Store, of course after clicking it I'm redirected to Microsoft Store App.

I wanted to do the same by launching **Windows Settings** and if possible I wanted to redirect the client specifically to **Settings** > **Update & Security** > **Check for Updates**.

I have a thought that it can be done using `JavaScript` but I'm not sure. I found the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34539718/how-does-this-javascript-open-windows-settings-in-firefox) but I think it is specifically to [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) and it confused me.

Comment: I don't think you can do such a thing :/

Comment: Not possible as far as I'm aware. JS in the browser doesn't interact with the OS directly, it just gives you a URL that the MS store can read, which then launches the MS store.

Comment: Nothing confusing. You need to break security as a user to allow the page to do it

Comment: Not sure if it would work from JavaScript, but there are Uri you can use when creating shortcuts to jump to specific control panel locations. Eg `ms-settings:windowsupdate`

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work for everyone. I've just searched for `Windows 10 update` using Microsoft Edge and there was a button "Check for updates", I clicked the button and the Windows Settings opened up. I copy the link and paste it to chrome and it worked, here it is: 

ms-settings:windowsupdate?activationSource=SMC-IA-4027667

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that it is possible, but I'm not sure though if this is part of JavasScript, the list of commands can be found in [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app), there are multiple options and not just for Windows Settings.

What I am looking for is `ms-settings:windowsupdate`.

**Example of usage**

```html
<a href="ms-settings:windowsupdate">Check for updates</a>
```